# After insert trigger doesn't work in ms sql 2014

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table say columns are ID and REFERENCE_ID.ID is Pkey and autoincrement is set on that.After insert ,below trigger is used to update the REFERENCE_ID which basically appends the inserted ID along with the date.

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ReferenceIDTrigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[TABLE1]    AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

  update TABLE1 set REFERENCE_ID = CONVERT([varchar](2) , DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()))+ SUBSTRING( CONVERT([varchar](4) , DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())),3,4)+ CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(50))  WHERE   ID=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE1)

END
```

This works fine when manually insert a record through sql designer.However when insert through java it says pkey is not found for the table error.

PS: This is recently migrated from 2010 to 2012 sql and it works fine in 2010 even when insert through java.What could be wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the relevant Java code you use to make the `INSERT`?

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen, if it works in the designer, we need to see what the actual call is via JAVA to help debug.  I/we suggest a data concern.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you want to do a `max(id)` here, you may want to join to the `INSERTED` table by `ID` [Of Interest](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d246ecea-8d80-47f4-a955-472eae9ac36b/trigger-get-values-from-updated?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this,

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ReferenceIDTrigger]

ON  [dbo].[TABLE1]

FOR INSERT

AS

declare @id int

select @id =Id from Inserted

BEGIN

update t1
        set REFERENCE_ID = CONVERT(varchar , DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()))+ SUBSTRING( CONVERT(varchar , DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())),3,4)+ CAST(i.ID AS VARCHAR(50))

```
    where id =@id
```

END;